# Schema names in psycopg2 identifiers

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to use the sql submodule of psycopg2 to write clean dynamic SQL:

```
from psycopg2 import sql
...
cursor.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {}").format(sql.Identifier('myschema.mytable'))
```

This creates the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "myschema.mytable"
```

Here I get an `Relation "myschema.mytable" not found.` exception.

How do I handle the schema name properly? The following statements would work, but how do I create them with psycopg2?

```
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable
SELECT * FROM myschema."mytable"
SELECT * FROM "myschema"."mytable"
```

edit: clarified schema prefix

Comment: I just tried it in DBeaver: `SELECT * FROM mytable;` works fine while `SELECT * FROM "mytable";` gives an error. I have to add that mytable contains an schema prefix, which may cause the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The construction

```
sql.Identifier('myschema.mytable')
```

is treated as a single [quoted identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), as can be seen from the produced query. You should pass the schema and table name as separate identifiers to format:

```
cursor.execute(sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {}.{}").format(
    sql.Identifier('myschema'),
    sql.Identifier('mytable'))
```

Note that the schema and table name must match exactly, case and all, since `psycopg2`'s [SQL string composition tools](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) produce quoted identifiers, and quoted identifiers are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

> But the table in my PostgreSQL database is unquoted on purpose. This means mytable exists, but "mytable" does not.

You misunderstand what quotes do. In your case (i.e. a case without special characters in table name) the only thing double quotes do is they make the name case sensitive. If you have table with name `MyTable` then

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

works because it is case insensitive while

```
SELECT * FROM "mytable";
```

does not because it is case sensitive. However

```
SELECT * FROM "MyTable";
```

will work and this is what you are looking for.

---

The other problem (as noted by @IljaEverilä in comments) is this:

```
SELECT * FROM "myschema.mytable"
```

which postgres treats as a table with name `myschema.mytable` because you've quoted the whole thing. I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM "myschema"."mytable"
```

i.e. you need a separate identifier for schema and seperate for table joined by `.`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Since **version 2.8** (released in Apr 4, 2019), you can pass multiple strings to `sql.Identifier` to represent a **qualified identifier** (e.g. a schema name + a table name).

```py
cursor.execute(
    sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {table}").format(
        table=sql.Identifier("myschema", "mytable")
    )
)

# SELECT * FROM "myschema"."mytable"
```

See: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier

Comment: This is so much better, keeps the actual query little cleaner.